# Pandas: Stacked bar chart of a column of dictionaries of key and values

Tags: python, pandas, plot, stacked-chart

I have a pandas dataframe as follows but with more rows:

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> data = {'First':  ['First value', 'Second value'],
'Second': [{'NOUN': 13, 'VERB': 8, 'PRON': 3}, {'PROPN': 2, 'VERB': 10, 'NOUN': 11}],}

>>> df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['First','Second'])
```

I would like to plot the values using a stacked bar chart. I am new to python, so I am not sure how I can do that with a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would import the dictionary differently:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

data = {'First':  ['First value', 'Second value'],
'Second': [{'NOUN': 13, 'VERB': 8, 'PRON': 3}, {'PROPN': 2, 'VERB': 10, 'NOUN': 11}],}

df = pd.DataFrame(data["Second"], index=data["First"])
df.plot(kind="bar", stacked="True")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]